# Probability: How to prove $P[A\cap B^c] = P[A] - P[A \cap B]$ without using set subtraction

Tags: probability, proof-writing

I would like to show using basic probability axioms:

$$P[A\cap B^c] = P[A] - P[A \cap B]$$ (Note that this relationship is immediate from a Venn diagram)

and I cannot use set subtraction i.e. assume that $P[A\backslash B]$ is not defined

---

**Attempt 1:**

Start with De Morgan's Law and complements.

\begin{align*}
P[A \cap B^c] &= P[(A^c \cup B)^c]\\
& = 1 - P[A^c \cup B]\\
& = 1 - (P[A^c] + P[B] - P[A^c \cap B])\\
& = 1 - (1 - P[A] + P[B] - P[(A \cup B^c)^c])\\
& = 1 - (1 - P[A] + P[B] - (1 - P[(A \cup B^c)]))\\
& = ... 
\end{align*}

It seems whatever I do I cannot get a $P[A \cap B]$ on the right hand side.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: I don't quite understand the restrictions. Is it valid to write $A$ as the disjoint union $A=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^c)$ to conclude
$
P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)
$
and consequently $P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$?

Comment: What do you mean? $A \backslash B$ is the same as $A \cap B^c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use set subtraction.

You just have to show $A~=~ (A\cap B)~\cup~ (A\cap B^\complement)$ *and* that the two parts of this union are disjoint.

That done, the properties of a probability measure will then guarantee : $$\mathsf P(A)=\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(A\cap B^\complement)$$

Immediately after a little algebraic rearrangement, we have what was to be shown:$$\mathsf P(A\cap B^\complement) ~=~ \mathsf P(A)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)$$

$$$$